# ProcessMaker 4 community - why can not use service task element

Tags: processmaker

As my question says.

One of the BPMN 2.0 features is the service task element in which one can set a service enpoint to be consumed. I'm able to use this element in WSO2 but not in processmaker 4.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details?  This works fine in ProcessMaker 4.  Inside your service task, you will name which connector you want to use.  Your connectors are created using our Connector builder which allows you to build a connector using any API.  None of this requires any coding and it is very easy to use.

thanks,